# Creating iptables rules based on traffic?

Tags: iptables, sles

Is there a solution (besides doing "-j LOG" and manually geting the rules) for iptables where I can start a "recoding" for the traffic on a Linux server and based on that a script/solution would provide me with the iptables rules that are needed for the recorded traffic to be allowed?

ps.: since there is not even an iptables tag on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - thats why I posted this question on UNIX stackexchange, but please say if there is a better place to ask.

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iptables 1603
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iptables 2248
https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iptables 5908

or maybe if no one knows on UNIX stack. maybe trying on Serverfault :)

Comment: What do you mean by "recording traffic"? Adding iptables rules on the fly is trivial - you can do that via `iptables -A/-I`

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). IPtables can record state directly and modify flow based on state, without this baroquity of invoking external scripts. You should describe the *real* problem and leave it up to the answerers to decide whether invoking external scripts is the best way to solve it.

Comment: we want to harden the server with proper iptables rules, but we first need to know what is the LEGAL traffic.